# Is it possible to metasploit without the shell.exe running on victim's computer?

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux

Whenever you have to get control of your victim's pc then you have to run the exe generated from msfvenom where the payload is set. So is there a way to to metasploit without the exe running or any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused. But even so Metasploit provides you (and not restricting to)with scanners, vulnerability exploits and shells.

You can gain acces in a machine by:

1. Executing a shell on the victim machine
2. Exploiting a vulnerability on the machine
3. Brute-forcing or intercepting an account or bypassing an authentication

Also see:

For 1: Reverse TCP Shell.

For 2: Psexec or any known exploits.

For 3: Smb login, intercept, guest vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say in general you have to find a way to execute arbitrary code on the victims machine. That could be an Exe, but also some PE Injections, DLLs, Scripts or Macros on the victims machine or exploiting an Remote Code vulnerability, which could be either a crafted Website or Document or directly contacting a network port on the victims machine (rarely possible).